# MS Access Query - Ignoring 'Order By' Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT u.UserLastName, u.UserID, SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 'h') * 60 *60)) as hourSeconds, SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 'n') * 60)) as minSeconds,
                SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 's'))) as seconds, COUNT(*) as 'callCount'
                FROM Calls AS c INNER JOIN User AS u ON c.UserID = u.UserID
                WHERE c.CallDate BETWEEN format(NOW(), 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00') AND format(Now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59') AND u.UserLastName NOT IN ('Britt','Jason','System')
                GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserLastName
                ORDER BY 'callCount' DESC;
```

I've spent forever trying different techniques to sort this query using the "ORDER BY" clause. What is incorrect? It simply runs the query with no errors but seems to sort by the u.UserID field instead. No matter what I do I cannot get the ORDER BY clause to order any field!

Comment: I was having the same issue with a very simple select query involving only one table and without any aliases or aggregating functions anywhere in the query.  It didn't work, but a rather clumsy workaround did.  I simply made up another query using the first query as if it were a table, and this time the sorting worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont want to use a string as a column name.

Try this.

also, if I recall correctly, you cant order and group. so a sub select groups, and you can order the results...

```
Select * from (
    SELECT 
        u.UserLastName, 
        u.UserID, 
        SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 'h') * 60 *60)) as hourSeconds, 
        SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 'n') * 60)) as minSeconds,
        SUM(Format(c.CallLength, 's')) as seconds, 
        COUNT(*) as callCount 
    FROM Calls AS c 
    INNER JOIN User AS u ON c.UserID = u.UserID

    WHERE c.CallDate BETWEEN format(NOW(), 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00') AND 
          format(Now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59') AND 
          u.UserLastName NOT IN ('Britt','Jason','System')
    GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserLastName
)
ORDER BY callCount DESC;
```

if Your column name cannot be used because it is a keyword or multiple words. try putting square braces around it.

[callCount]

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use square braces for that purpose. However, I've tried that and I get an error: "Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Comment: That may have been a typo on my part. I have amended the post with a new query. try that one.

Comment: Continues to give me the error "Too Few Parameters. Expected 1." Hmm.

Comment: I cannot be sure, but if I remember correctly, there may be issues with order and grouping, Try the nested query, and break it down in smaller pieces to see if you can find out what part is asking for one parameter.

Comment: Well Jason, you sold me on this site. That was it. It was the order by clause that was asking for the 1 parameter. And your query above solved it.

Answer (score 2):

If your original query returned the data you want without error, and the only problem was the ORDER BY, I think this simple change is the way to go.

```
SELECT
    u.UserLastName,
    u.UserID,
    SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 'h') * 60 *60)) as hourSeconds,
    SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 'n') * 60)) as minSeconds,
    SUM((Format(c.CallLength, 's'))) as seconds,
    COUNT(*) as callCount
FROM Calls AS c INNER JOIN User AS u ON c.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE
    c.CallDate BETWEEN format(NOW(), 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00')
    AND format(Now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59')
    AND u.UserLastName NOT IN ('Britt','Jason','System')
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.UserLastName
ORDER BY 6 DESC;
```

When you assign an alias to a field (or expression), you can't use that alias name in the ORDER BY.  However you can refer to it by its ordinal position in the field list.

Comment: Thanks for your help HansUp. Very good to know, and is the answer to my unexplained resolution above! Thanks for sharing your knowledge.